# Understanding Hadoop through matrix multiplication using R

Tags: r, hadoop, matrix

This is just an attempt to understand Hadoop, R and the best practice for doing certain things that really leverages the best of both Hadoop and R.

If the goal is to multiply two matrices A*B when these two matrices are stored in Hadoop then traditional methods of multiplying two matrices A & B in R is against the logic of big data. The reason we are having this discussion in the first place is because r chokes on big data and it is impossible to multiple two large matrices in R ? If I am correct so far, matrix multiplication should be performed using shell scripts/ unix scripts, is this correct ? we just use R to display the results of this operation (matrix multiplication) that occurred behind the scene via shell script, am I correct ?

Interested to know your thoughts on this topic.

Comment: Check out [mining massive dataset](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/book.pdf), maybe page 30.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. that pdf is exactly what the doctor prescribed :) awesome.

Comment: Do you think you can answer your own question so it will be helpful for the coming readers or you want me to do it?